# How to get post content from an array of ids?

Tags: posts, get-posts, post-content

How do I get post content if I have an array of id's. Basically, I have a function that get post content if you provide an ID. but it doesn't work if I have an array of id's. My function is:

```
function get_post_by_id($id){
    $post_content = get_post($id);
    $content=$post_content->post_content;

    return $content;
}
```

Now if I pass an id to this function it will work. For example:

```
    $last_post = get_post_by_id(83);

    print_r($last_post);
```

How do I get `post_content` if I have an array of `ID's`.Something like:

```
$last_post = get_post_by_id(array(83,80,92));
```

It doesn't work this way now. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first query works you can try something like this :

```
function get_post_by_id($id){
$content = array();
foreach ($id as $key => $value) {
    $post_content = get_post($value);
    $content[]=$post_content->post_content;
}

return $content;
}
```

Cheers,
phpbits

Comment: No problem :). Happy to help.